# How to convert curl command to JavaScript fetch

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch-api

I'm building a react project and I'm using an API, in the API doc they just provided this curl command:

```
#!/bin/bash 
apiKey="yourApiKey"
secret="yourSecret"
curl -i \
-X GET \
-H 'Accept:application/json' \
-H 'Api-key:'$apiKey'' \
-H 'X-Signature:'$(echo -n ${apiKey}${secret}$(date +%s)|sha256sum|awk '{ print $1}')'' \
https://example.com
```

How can I convert this code to a JavaScript fetch?

I tried this code:

```
  const sec = Date.now() / 1000 + "";
  const myString = "someApiKey" + "apiSecret" + sec;
  const bitArr = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(myString);
  const hash = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(bitArr);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
         "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "content/type": "application/json",
        "Api-key":'someApiKey',
        'X-Signature': hash
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

but it gave me error:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name

Comment: Did you try googling the error message?  Did you find anything useful?  There are several questions like this on SO.  Hint: `"content/type": "application/json"`

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1

Fix content type

Try 'content-type' instead of 'content/type'

## Step 2

Log text instead of json to see what was returned

```
.then((res) => res.text())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Didn't work gave me this error instead SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'S', "See /corsd"... is not valid JSON

Comment: So you are getting a response now.  Try to debug what is sent using res.text() instead of res.json(), and then logging the result.  I will post in solution.

Comment: Yes i got "See /corsdemo for more info", i think there's an issue related to cors i updated the question so you can see the proxy i used to forward the request. i also had a previous question two days ago about this specific cors issue i had before.

Comment: If you are now receiving a response from your proxy, your current question has been answered.